# Ada2012: inherited discriminant not allowed here

Tags: oop, ada

I have the following problem and I don't really understand why:

```
procedure Main is
  
  type Component_t (Id : Natural) is tagged limited null record;
  
  type Root_t (Id : Natural) is tagged limited null record;
  
  type Child_t is limited new Root_t with
     record
       component : Component_t(Id => Id);
     end record;

begin
   --  Insert code here.
   null;
end Main;
```

9:38 -> error: Id is not visible

error: non-visible declaration at line 5

error: inherited discriminant not allowed here (RM 3.8 (12), 3.8.1 (6))

I'm not sure if the mentioned RM's are the following:

**[3.8 12/3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-8.html)**
A name that denotes a noninherited discriminant is allowed within the declaration of the type, but not within the discriminant_part. If the discriminant is used to define the constraint of a component, the bounds of an entry family, or the constraint of the parent subtype in a derived_type_definition, then its name shall appear alone as a direct_name (not as part of a larger expression or expanded name). A discriminant shall not be used to define the constraint of a scalar component.

**[3.8.1 6](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-8-1.html)**
The discriminant_direct_name shall resolve to denote a discriminant (called the discriminant of the variant_part) specified in the known_discriminant_part of the full_type_declaration that contains the variant_part. The expected type for each discrete_choice in a variant is the type of the discriminant of the variant_part.

If I declare child_t as follows it compiles, but it seems really weird to me. Is it ok and acceptable? Are there any less verbose options to solve it?

```
type Child_t (Id : Natural) is limited new Root_t (Id => Id) with
   record
     component : Component_t(Id => Id);
   end record;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC the reason is:

```
type Child_t is limited new Root_t with
```

So, what you have here is `Root_T` doesn't supply a value to the discriminant. (You could, for example have `Type Numeric is limited Root_Type( ID => A_Type ) --...`, which says that Numeric and its descendants are have `ID` set to `A_Type`.)

> If I declare child_t as follows it compiles, but it seems really weird
> to me. Is it ok and acceptable? Are there any less verbose options to
> solve it?

```
type Child_t (Id : Natural) is limited new Root_t (Id => Id) with
   record
     component : Component_t(Id => Id);
   end record;
```

This is the correct way to say "Child_t is discriminated and supplies its discriminant's value to Root_T's discriminant-value."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't usually use discriminated records but since I don't want to change the "Id" I started thinking to use them as in my question. I think the solution is not intuitive because I though the discriminant will be inherited too. In fact, GNATStudio shows two Id's within the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

It can’t be ARM 3.8.1, because that’s about variant records, which yours aren’t.

Looking at [AARM 3.8(12)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-3-8.html#p12) - well, much as I love Ada, this is clearly not aimed at ordinary mortals.

I think you should be glad you found a working solution.

Comment: I'm using GNATPro 23.1 so I'll contact AdaCore to clarify if there's a compiler bug or something else. I'm agree, I'm an ordinary mortal and I think I'm not clever enough to understand correctly the most of the RM, but I have to say you end intuiting things. I'll then be proud of me hahaha. Thanks Simon!